# How can I get a report of changes made to Teams?

Tags: powershell, export, report, microsoft-teams

I am using the script below to populate multiple Teams from a .csv:

```
# Read team users from CSV file
$TeamUsers = Import-CSV "Import_Path.csv"
$i = 0
# Group the objects by their TeamDesc property, so we only query each group once
$TeamUsers | Group-Object TeamDesc | ForEach-Object {
    #Get the GroupId of this Group
    $groupId = (Get-Team -DisplayName $_.Name).GroupId
    #If the Group couldn't be found, just skip below logic
    if(-not $groupId) { return }
    #If the Group could be found, create a hashtable for future splatting
    $params = @{ GroupId = $groupId }
    #now we can enumerate each object in each group of objects
    foreach($user in $_.Group){
        try {
            # create a hashtable for splatting progress
            $progress = @{
              PercentComplete = $i++ / $TeamUsers.Count * 100
              Activity        = 'Adding Users to MS Teams!!'
              Status = 'Working on Team: "{0}" and User: "{1}"' -f $_.Name, $user.UserPrincipalName
            }
            Write-Progress @progress
            # add this user with this role to the hashtable
            $params['User'] = $user.UserPrincipalName
            $params['Role'] = $user.Role
            Add-TeamUser @params
        }
        catch {
            ('Error occurred for {0} - {1}' -f $user.TeamName, $user.UserPrincipalName),
            $_.ToString() | Write-Warning
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to include the ability to export a report of the actions taken during the run. Ideally, at the end of the script, I would be able to collect a file that describes which users have been added to which Teams. Currently, the script will display actions in the PowerShell interface with the `Write-Progress` line, but I would like to be able to have a tangible report as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if there is an easier way, but I would create a new object containing the relevant information, and then at the end of the process, export a new CSV.

So at the start, declare a new array:

```
$AllActions = @()
```

Then, after the "Add-TeamUser" line, add these in:

```
$ActionObj = New-Object PSObject
$ActionObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name GroupID -value $GroupID
$ActionObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name User -Value $user.UserPrincipalName     
$ActionObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name Role -Value $User.Role

$AllActions += $ActionObj
```

Now, down at the end, add in:

```
$AllActions | Export-csv .\AllActionsTaken.csv
```

So the final script would be:

```
# Read team users from CSV file
$AllActions = @()
$TeamUsers = Import-CSV "Import_Path.csv"
$i = 0
# Group the objects by their TeamDesc property, so we only query each group once
$TeamUsers | Group-Object TeamDesc | ForEach-Object {
    #Get the GroupId of this Group
    $groupId = (Get-Team -DisplayName $_.Name).GroupId
    #If the Group couldn't be found, just skip below logic
    if(-not $groupId) { return }
    #If the Group could be found, create a hashtable for future splatting
    $params = @{ GroupId = $groupId }
    #now we can enumerate each object in each group of objects
    foreach($user in $_.Group){
        try {
            # create a hashtable for splatting progress
            $progress = @{
              PercentComplete = $i++ / $TeamUsers.Count * 100
              Activity        = 'Adding Users to MS Teams!!'
              Status = 'Working on Team: "{0}" and User: "{1}"' -f $_.Name, $user.UserPrincipalName
            }
            Write-Progress @progress
            # add this user with this role to the hashtable
            $params['User'] = $user.UserPrincipalName
            $params['Role'] = $user.Role
            Add-TeamUser @params
            $ActionObj = New-Object PSObject
            $ActionObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name GroupID -value $GroupID
            $ActionObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name User -Value $user.UserPrincipalName     
            $ActionObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name Role -Value $User.Role
    
            $AllActions += $ActionObj
        }
        catch {
            ('Error occurred for {0} - {1}' -f $user.TeamName, $user.UserPrincipalName),
            $_.ToString() | Write-Warning
        }
    }
}
$AllActions | Export-csv .\AllActioonsTaken.csv
```